# How to calculate b0 and b1 in Simple Linear Regression With R?

Tags: r, parameters, regression, linear-regression, estimation

I'm trying to create a program with R to calculate manually b0 and b1  in Simple Linear Regression with Least Square Method.

```
regression=function(num,x,y)
switch(num,
  b1 = {n = 5
        b = (n*sum(x*y)-sum(x)*sum(y))/(n*sum(x^2)-sum(x)^2)
        print(b)},
  b0 = {n = 5
        b = (n*sum(x*y)-sum(x)*sum(y))/(n*sum(x^2)-sum(x)^2)
        a = mean(y)-b1*mean(x)
        print(a)}
)
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y = c(2, 1, 4, 5, 3)
regression(b1, x, y)
regression(b0, x, y)
```

But it fails

Comment: "Fails" how? Error? What error? Warning? Wrong answer? R crashes?

Comment: you need an extra set of curly brackets for functions don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way of defining your function is as follows,

```
regression=function(num,x,y){
  n=num
  b1 = (n*sum(x*y)-sum(x)*sum(y))/(n*sum(x^2)-sum(x)^2)
  b0=mean(y)- b1*mean(x)
  return(c(b0,b1))

}
```

With this, you can get a vector containing your b0 and b1. In the code below, I have shown how you can access this and plot the resulting regression line.

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y = c(2, 1, 4, 5, 3)

b0<-regression(5,x,y)[1]
b1<-regression(5,x,y)[2]

regression_line<-b0+b1*x

plot(x,y)
lines(regression_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.

1. `b0` and `b1` don't exist when you call the function, so you can't pass them in as arguments---you can pass them in as strings, which is what `switch` expects. So when you call `regression`, call it as `regression("b1", x, y)` or `regression("b0", x, y)`.
2. In the `b0 = {...}` section of code, you call an intermediate result `b`, but later try to reference `b1`. Again, `b1` doesn't exist, so call your intermediate result `b1`, not `b`.

Address those issues, and I think your function will work just fine :)